# How to bind value inside a Pug.js filter

Tags: javascript, pug, template-engine, pugjs

I'm tying to bind some value inside a [Pug.js](https://pugjs.org/) filter. But that filter works fine the value doesn't bind.

**Output Result with the filter**

```
<style>.#{cs_1}{font-family:monospace !important;color:#a1292c !important}.#{cs_1}:hover{background-color:transparent !important;text-decoration:underline !important}.#{cs_2}{position:absolute;font-size:11px;text-transform:none;left:80px;top:12px;border-left:1px solid #ccc;padding-left:6px}.#{cs_3}{white-space:nowrap}</style>
```

**Output Result without the Filter**

```
<style>
    .eTWkI {
        font-family: monospace !important;
        color: #a1292c !important;
    }
    .eTWkI:hover {
        background-color: transparent !important;
        text-decoration: underline !important;
    }
    .Rzorr {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-transform: none;
        left: 80px;
        top: 12px;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding-left: 6px;
    }
    .vMvwp {
        white-space: nowrap; 
    }
</style>
```

**Pug.js Code**

> Note: That `:minifycss` filter made with [uglifycss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifycss) module

```
- var length = 5
- var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz_-"

- var cs_1 = utils.randomString(length, chars)
- var cs_2 = utils.randomString(length, chars)
- var cs_3 = utils.randomString(length, chars)

style
    :minifycss
        .#{cs_1} {
            font-family: monospace !important;
            color: #a1292c !important;
        }
        .#{cs_1}:hover {
            background-color: transparent !important;
            text-decoration: underline !important;
        }
        .#{cs_2} {
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 11px;
            text-transform: none;
            left: 80px;
            top: 12px;
            border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding-left: 6px;
        }
        .#{cs_3} {
            white-space: nowrap; 
        }
```

**So the Filter looks like :**

```
require('pug').filters = {

    minifycss: (text, options) => {
        if (!text) return;
        return uglifycss.processString(text, options);
    }

};
```

Comment: What is the actual output of the code? Is nothing there, or is it unexpected output?

Comment: @SheaBelsky. No there is no errors. Just that Output result only

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Pug filters are run at compile time, and don't allow for variable/dynamic content. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/1782) for more info. You can export the `minifycss` function you've written, then require it within Jade (as is done in [this related GitHub issue](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2604)) in order to get your filter code to work. You'd need to export the `require` function to Pug (`locals.require = require` in your route), then use it to require the `minifycss` function from elsewhere.

However, [it also appears as though the above issue was fixed in Pug 2.0.0 beta11](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2647#issuecomment-277506566). Depending on what version of Pug you're using, that may be the cause of the issue.